# Are there more true statements than false ones?

Tags: logic, computability, peano-axioms

Let us enumerate all statements of PA or ZFC by length, upto n characters, then in the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$, what proportion of statements are provably true, provably false, or independent?

Ok, no enumeration necessary, just count all of length less then n and take the limit.

Is it perhaps 50%,50%,0%?

What if we discard all statements which are simply the negation character in front of a shorter statement?

What is the asymptotic density of independent statements?

Is any non-trivial results of this sort known for any theory?

Comment: Since all three sets are countably infinite. So it amounts to how you are going to enumerate them.

Comment: By length, as I already said.

Comment: There are infinitely many statement of length $3$. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: You count the symbols of the statement with multiplicity. What length did you have in mind?

Comment: $x_1=x_1, x_2=x_2, x_3=x_3,\ldots$

Comment: And 3 =SS1 etc. So those arent of length 3.

Comment: Okay, now I don't even know what is the language that you are using. $3$ is not the language I know for $\sf PA$ (which only includes $=,\leq$, $0,S,+,\cdot$, the logical connectives and quantifiers and $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ for free variables).

Comment: Negating a sentence changes its truth value so it seems that true and false percentages should be equal.

Comment: Is it possible to find ALL independent theorems of a theory ?

Comment: @Asaf Is that the only problem you see?  If so, it seems rather easily fixed, by choosing a single canonical representative from each equivalence class of formulas: If the formula contains only one free variable, it must be $x_1$; if the formula has two free variables, they must be $x_1$ and $x_2$ and the leftmost variable must be $x_1$; and so on.

Comment: @MJD: Yes, your suggestion fails for $\forall x_1(x_1=x_1),\forall x_2(x_2=x_2)$ and so on; but that too can be easily corrected. This is just an example of ambiguity within this post. In the comments the OP also pointed out that $3$ is in the language, to my knowledge, $3$ is just a shorthand for $SSS0$, but the comment seemed to indicate something else. Therefore, I still wait for the OP to clarify and remove ambiguities like that. Ideally an enumeration which is not handwaved around like this one, will also be given.

Comment: I meant $x_3=x_{SSS0}$. Thats just one suggestion to make it non-trivial, I am interested in any type of results of this sort.

Comment: But the variables are not indexed by the language, but rather the meta-language. So writing $x_{SSS0}$ makes no sense. I still feel that you need to write down exactly what the language you are using it. Then perhaps we can formulate things slightly better (e.g. consider $\varphi\equiv\psi$ if and only if $\sf PA$ proves $\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$; there are countably many equivalence classes, from each one choose the one which is both the shortest, and the variables appearing (quantified or not) appear in order (first $x_1$ then $x_2$ and so on) and without jumps), and then we can proceed.

Comment: Ok, so x_i counts as i characters. Or your suggestion is better. But I dont want to exclude other interesting formulations.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean 'and then'? You dont need to order them, just count all of length less then n. Then take the limit.

Comment: @hot_queen Not necessarily, if you got a proof of that you should post it as an answer.

Comment: What you're asking about has been studied in recent years by [Marek Zaionc](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Marek+Zaionc%22+asymptotic) for various systems of propositional logic. However, I think anything close to what you're asking about is not going to be done anytime soon.

Comment: No need for being rude; insulting and dismissing researchers in the field is not the way to get help on your problem. Your question is ill-posed as it stands currently, pointing it out should actually be considered help.

Comment: David Speyer has some nice things to say here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4454/how-many-of-the-true-sentences-are-provable

Comment: @user117658 Please watch your language. And if you have problems with the need for clarity in mathematics, you are free not ask here anymore.

Comment: A last amusing thought: Working in ZFC, you cannot show that the fraction of provable statements is less than 1 since that would imply the consistency of ZFC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under certain reasonable assumptions, the independent statements are of full density. See [https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~cristian/aam.pdf](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Ecristian/aam.pdf)

**Edit:** As David E Speyer points out, the results of the above paper are, to say the least, questionable. Thus, all we can say is that the proportions of true, false, and independent statements are all positive. Precisely what these proportions are would depend on how we code the statements and measure their quantity.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; the proportion of **true** statements that are independent goes to $1$ according to the paper, but that's not the same as the proportion of **all** statements that are independent!

Comment: @user21820: Each false statement corresponds to a true one, by prefixing a ¬, or by deleting an already prefixed ¬. So the false statements are, asymptotically with respect to statement length, of the same density as the true ones. A statement is independent if neither it nor its negation is provable. So, if the proportion of true statements that are independent is asymptotically $1$, then the proportion of false statements that are independent is asymptotically $1$ too. Hence the proportion of all statements, true or false, is asymptotically $1$.

Comment: Hmm it's not clear to me it's rigorously correct since you're basically using the assumption that on average a random true statement of length $n$ is equally likely to be a negation than not. That is maybe why it's stated as an open problem at the end of the very paper you linked to. But I intuitively buy the argument, though you should make clear what is proven by the paper.

Comment: This issue keeps coming up and I keep raising the same objection  https://mathoverflow.net/a/7902/297 : A positive density of statements are of the form "1=1 or X" . I wish someone would explain to me why I am wrong.