# To what degree are arbitrary true statements about the natural numbers provable?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms, incompleteness

Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem states that if we have a recursive and consistent set of axioms $A$ in $\mathcal{L}_{\text{NT}}$, then there is a true first order statement about natural numbers $\sigma$ such that $A \not \vdash \sigma$.

Thus, the set of provable statements about the natural numbers is a proper subset of the set of true statements about the natural numbers. I was wondering what can be said about the set of provable statements with regards to its size in comparison with the set of true statements. Clearly they are both infinite sets, but, in terms of measure theory, topology, or density, is there something that can be said?

Comment: You can’t really talk about the “percentage” of a countable set. You can talk about the density.

Comment: The answer to this is completely dependent on how you intend to "randomly generate a true statement about the natural numbers".

Comment: @AlexKruckman Well, there might be some unexpected robustness, which would be quite interesting (incidentally, I can't resist using this as an opportunity to mention [the singular importance of the number $0.625$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007211001333)).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ha! That's a very amusing result. I agree that there could be some interesting robustness, if the question is formulated correctly (though I expect that even so it would be extremely difficulty to analyze the situation). But we're talking about probability measures on a countable set. Since infinitely many truths are provable in PA and infinitely many are not, nothing more can be said without giving some sort of restriction on the class of measures under consideration.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Oh sure, a lot of work is needed. My point was mostly meant to un-discourage the OP: there are genuine problems with their question but I don't want them to come away from this thinking that it's a bad one per se.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I agree.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I wasn't sure how to best formulate the question, as I realized it would be fairly open ended, and I'm realizing I definitely could have worded it better. A measure theoretic argument or an argument regarding natural density would be the type of thing I am looking for, if such an argument exists. 

The reason I am asking is because it occurred to me that it could be the case that actually "almost none" of the true statements about natural numbers are actually provable, which would show that "provability" is actually a very weak condition.

Comment: I have edited the post to be more clear.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491438/462).